# Filling time series column values with last known value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, imputation

I have a Pandas time series dataframe like this:

```
id .. .. ..(some cols) 1/1/20 1/2/20 1/3/20 1/4/20 1/5/20 1/6/20 ....
1                      10     20     0      40     0      50
2                      10     30     30     0      0      50
.
.
```

I want to `ffill` the 0s in the columns with the last known value to get something like this:

```
id .. .. ..(some cols) 1/1/20 1/2/20 1/3/20 1/4/20 1/5/20 1/6/20 ....
1                      10     20     20     40     40      50
2                      10     30     30     30     30      50
.
.
```

Assuming there are some other columns between `id` and the time series columns, how do I `ffill` the dataframe like this? I know something like `df.ffill(axis = 1)` works for Null values, but I wasn't able to find anything to modify it to work with `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `ffill` with `mask` and `update`

```
df.update(df.filter(like='/').mask(lambda x : x==0).ffill(1))
```

Comment: is there a way to use this single liner for `0` and `np.nan`? This doesn't seem to work `df.update(df.filter(like='/').mask(lambda x : x==0 or np.nan).ffill(1))`

Comment: @codingenthusiast df.filter(like='/').mask(lambda x : (x==0) | x.isnull())

Comment: It's still not working on empty cells. Any idea why?

Comment: @codingenthusiast empty is '' not null

Comment: `df.update(df.filter(like='/').mask(lambda x: (x == float(np.nan) | (x == 0)).ffill(1)))` gives me `TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [float]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my solution can be a bit naive, but you can convert your values of interest to nan and then use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method. Just like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1,2,3,4,5],col2=[3,0,3,5,0],col3=[0,2,0,0,1]))
df[df==0]=np.nan
df.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)
```